# Determine if joined table has 1 or more than 1 matching rows. Is there a better way than GROUP BY and COUNT?

Tags: mysql, optimization, join, group-by

I join table A to table B and need to know if table B has 1 matching row or more than one.

Of course, I can do it with GROUP BY and COUNT, but it's an overkill, because it has to count all the matches and I don't need this info.

Is there a simple way to get the info I need (only one matching row or more) which short circuits the evaluation and stops when it knows the answer without scanning and counting all the remaining matches?

Or should I not care about this, becasue it's not a big performance hit and I should simply go with COUNT?

Comment: Can you run an `EXPLAIN` on your original query and share the result? You can then see which indexes it uses and how many rows it will process. It will give you a clue about the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the size of the DB, and your exact requirements.  Generally a count()/Group By/Having combination is a pretty efficient query, with the right indexes.  You could do it in a more complicated way, for example, having a trigger on after update that keeps a count table updated.

Are you seeing the count(*)/group/having combination giving you performance issues?

Comment: Not really. It involves a few thousand rows at most. I just wanted to know if there is a simple efficient way, because then I'd use that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know if there is one or more than one row for a certain join sql, meaning a matching row:

```sql
-- Without any sample SQL code, here's a return sample
SELECT B.SOMEJOINAPPLICABLECOLUMN
FROM A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
    ON A.SOMEJOINAPPLICABLECOLUMN = B.SOMEJOINAPPLICABLECOLUMN
WHERE 
    B.SOMEJOINAPPLICABLECOLUMN IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 2;
```

Naturally:

```
2 returned rows = more than one match
1 returned row  = one match
0 returned rows = no matches
```

Comment: And is it more efficient than GROUP BY and COUNT in your opinion? Is it worth it to use this instead of GROUP BY?

Comment: I must apologize... I can't tell you for sure in terms of speed.. You could compare the results of this query and yours by using `explain`, though... But this one definitely does not aggregate your data, nor does it have to return all rows... Maybe a more experienced 'stacker' can share his/her knowledge on this..